# RegEx Match VB.NET Select Case with no Case Else

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group, balancing-groups

I'm looking for a RegEx that will find Select Case Statements that have no Case Else in them.

Here's what I came up with so far

```
(?sm)^\s*Select Case.*(?<!^\s*Case Else.*)End Select
```

This one works perfectly except for cases that may have nested statements.

in my attempt to use balance groups, I came up with the following

```
Select Case(?>Select Case(?<DEPTH>)|End Select(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*?(?(DEPTH)(?!))End Select
```

Which correctly finds balanced groups of Select Case/End Selects but I'm having a hard time getting it to work with the (?

Heres some sample data:

```
Select Case
 Case :
  Select Case
   Case : Something
  End Select
  Case Else : SomethingElse
End Select
```

In this case it should match just the inner Select Case because the Outter has it's Case Else

```
Select Case
 Case :
  Select Case
   Case : Something
   Case Else : SomethingElse
  End Select
End Select
```

Should match then entire block because the inner has the Else but the outter doesnt.

```
Select Case
 Case :
  Select Case
   Case : Something
   Case Else : SomethingElse
  End Select
  Case Else : SomethingElseOutter
End Select
```

Should not match because both inner and outter selects have a Case Else

Comment: Does it have to be done in a single RegEx?

Comment: I was hoping for one. But yea, if worse comes to worse I will just drill down through them using loops in code.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

```
^[ \t]*Select[ ]Case.*\n                    # Start of 'Select Case' statement
(?>                                         # REPEAT as few as possible
    (?>[ \t]*)                              #   whitespace at beginning of line
    (?>                                     #   And
        (?<nested>Select[ ]Case)            #       there's a nested Select (+1 balancing group)
    |                                       #     Or
        (?(nested)                          #       If inside a nested statement
            (?<-nested>End[ ]Select)?       #           match 'End Select' (-1 balancing group)
        |                                   #       Else
            (?!Case[ ]Else)                 #           it can't match a 'Case Else'
        )                                   #
    )                                       #
    .*\n                                    #   Consume the whole line (go to next line)
)*?                                         # END REPEAT
(?(nested)(?!)|                             # If inside a nested statement, it can't match
[ \t]*End[ ]Select)                         # if outer statement, match the 'End Select'
```

One-liner:

```
^[ \t]*Select Case.*\n(?>(?>[ \t]*)(?>(?<nested>Select Case)|(?(nested)(?<-nested>End Select)?|(?!Case Else))).*\n)*?(?(nested)(?!)|[ \t]*End Select)
```

[Test on regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b+%5ct%5d*Select%5b+%5dCase.*%5cn++++++++++++++++++++%23+Start+of+%27Select+Case%27+statement%0d%0a(%3f%3e+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+REPEAT+as+few+as+possible%0d%0a++++(%3f%3e%5b+%5ct%5d*)++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+++whitespace+at+beginning+of+line%0d%0a++++(%3f%3e+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+++And%0d%0a++++++++(%3f%3cnested%3eSelect%5b+%5dCase)++++++++++++%23+++++++there%27s+a+nested+Select+(%2b1+balancing+group)%0d%0a++++%7c+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+++++Or%0d%0a++++++++(%3f(nested)++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+++++++If+inside+a+nested+statement%0d%0a++++++++++++(%3f%3c-nested%3eEnd%5b+%5dSelect)%3f+++++++%23+++++++++++match+%27End+Select%27+(-1+balancing+group)%0d%0a++++++++%7c+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+++++++Else%0d%0a++++++++++++(%3f!Case%5b+%5dElse)+++++++++++++++++%23+++++++++++it+can%27t+match+a+%27Case+Else%27%0d%0a++++++++)+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%0d%0a++++)+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23%0d%0a++++.*%5cn++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+++Consume+the+whole+line+(go+to+next+line)%0d%0a)*%3f+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+END+REPEAT%0d%0a(%3f(nested)(%3f!)%7c+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+If+inside+a+nested+statement%2c+it+can%27t+match%0d%0a%5b+%5ct%5d*End%5b+%5dSelect)+++++++++++++++++++++++++%23+if+outer+statement%2c+match+the+%27End+Select%27&i=Select+Case%0d%0a+Case+%3a%0d%0a++Select+Case%0d%0a+++Case+%3a+Something%0d%0a+++Case+Else+%3a+SomethingElse%0d%0a++End+Select%0d%0aEnd+Select&o=xm)

---

**Description**

The regex matches `Select Case` and then it tries to consume as few lines as it can until it finds an `End Select`. For each line:

- If there's a nested `Select Case`, it creates a Capture in `(?<nested>Select[ ]Case)`
- `(?(nested)`true`|`false`)` is an IF clause that:

  - If there's a capture for `nested` (i.e. inside a nested statement), it could substract a capture when `(?<-nested>End[ ]Select)?` matches (optional group).
  - Or if there isn't a capture (i.e. in the main statement), the line should not be an Else statement `(?!Case[ ]Else)`.

This is the logic behind [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/5290909). If it matches a nested `Select Case`, it creates a new capture, and if it matches an `End Select` it substracts the last capture. Therefore, only in the outer group there will be no captures stored.

We use that at the end of the pattern with `(?(nested)(?!)|[ \t]*End[ ]Select)`. If there's a capture it goes to `(?!)` (which can never match), fails and backtracks to keep consuming more lines. But if there are no captures, it can match `[ \t]*End[ ]Select` (or backtrack and consume more lines as well).

That's it.

Notice though that if there are two Select staments without a Case Else, nested one in another, only the outer statement will be matched. if you're interested in matching both, use

```
(?=(previous pattern))
```

and use `Match.Groups(1)` to get the text matched.