# using regular expression balancing groups to match nesting tags

Tags: c#, regex, balancing-groups

i'm trying use regular expression balancing groups to match nesting tags looks like this:

```
some text ...
 {list}
    nesting loop content
    {list}
        {list}
            {list}
                bala ...
            {/list}
        {/list}
    {/list}

{/list}
end
```

my expresson:

```
\{(?<NAME>.+?)\}
[^\{\}]*
    (
        (
            \{(?<NAME2>.+?)\}(?<OPEN>)
            [^\{\}]*?
        )
        (
            \{\/\<NAME2>\}(?<-OPEN>)
            [^\{\}]*?
        )
    )*
    (?(OPEN)(?!))  
\{\/\<NAME>\}
```

my problem:

```
 only last 2 level pair can match.
```

Comment: Use an html/xml parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, to match nested tags, you'd want something similar to:

```
(?>
  \{(?<Open>\w+)\}
  |
  \{/(?<-Open>\<Open>)\}
  |
  (?(Open)[^{}]+)
  )*
(?(Open)(?!))
```

[Working example: Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3e%0d%0a++%5c%7b%28%3f%3cOpen%3e%5cw%2b%29%5c%7d%0d%0a++%7c%0d%0a++%5c%7b%2f%28%3f%3c-Open%3e%5c%3cOpen%3e%29%5c%7d%0d%0a++%7c%0d%0a++%28%3f%28Open%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%0d%0a++%29*%0d%0a%28%3f%28Open%29%28%3f!%29%29&i=%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++nesting+loop+content%0d%0a++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++++++bala+...%0d%0a++++++++++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++nesting+loop+content%0d%0a++++%7bworld%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++%7bhello%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++++++bala+...%0d%0a++++++++++++%7b%2fhello%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a++++%7b%2fworld%7d%0d%0a%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a&o=x)

This way you can match nested tags of *different types*, which looks like what you're trying to do. For example, it would match this:

```
{list}
    nesting loop content
    {world}
        {list}
            {hello}
                bala ...
            {/hello}
        {/list}
    {/world}
{/list}
```

Notes:

- I'm using `(?(Open)[^{}]+)` so we only match free text if it is within tags.
- I'm using the same group for the top level and the inner levels.

---

Yours was pretty close. You are basically missing one alternation between the middle groups:

```
(
    \{(?<NAME2>.+?)\}(?<OPEN>)
    [^\{\}]*?
)
| # <---- This
(
    \{\/\<NAME2>\}(?<-OPEN>)
    [^\{\}]*?
)
```

[Working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%28%3f%3cNAME%3e.%2b%3f%29%5c%7d%0d%0a%5b%5e%5c%7b%5c%7d%5d*%0d%0a++++%28%0d%0a++++++++%28%0d%0a++++++++++++%5c%7b%28%3f%3cNAME2%3e.%2b%3f%29%5c%7d%28%3f%3cOPEN%3e%29%0d%0a++++++++++++%5b%5e%5c%7b%5c%7d%5d*%3f%0d%0a++++++++%29%7c%0d%0a++++++++%28%0d%0a++++++++++++%5c%7b%5c%2f%5c%3cNAME2%3e%5c%7d%28%3f%3c-OPEN%3e%29%0d%0a++++++++++++%5b%5e%5c%7b%5c%7d%5d*%3f%0d%0a++++++++%29%0d%0a++++%29*%0d%0a++++%28%3f%28OPEN%29%28%3f!%29%29++%0d%0a%5c%7b%5c%2f%5c%3cNAME%3e%5c%7d&i=%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++nesting+loop+content%0d%0a++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++++++bala+...%0d%0a++++++++++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a++++%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a%7blist%7d%0d%0a++++nesting+loop+content%0d%0a++++%7bworld%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7bworld%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++%7bhello%7d%0d%0a++++++++++++++++bala+...%0d%0a++++++++++++%7b%2fhello%7d%0d%0a++++++++%7b%2fhello%7d%0d%0a++++%7b%2fhello%7d%0d%0a%7b%2flist%7d%0d%0a&o=x)

However, you are always using the *last value* of `$NAME2`. `$NAME2` is a stack, but you never pop values from it, only push. This causes a bug: it would also match this string (which is probably wrong):

```
{list}             # Set $Name = "world"
    nesting loop content
    {world}             # Set $Name2 = "world"
        {world}         # Set $Name2 = "world"
            {hello}     # Set $Name2 = "hello"
                bala ...
            {/hello}    # Match $Name2 ("hello")
        {/hello}        # Match $Name2 ("hello")
    {/hello}            # Match $Name2 ("hello")
{/list}            # Match $Name ("list")
```

See also:

- [What are regular expression Balancing Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799/7586)
- [How to make balancing group capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23349893/7586)