# How to get text between nested parentheses?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Reg Expression for Getting Text Between parenthesis ( ), I had tried but i am not getting the RegEx. For this example

`Regex.Match(script, @"\((.*?)\)").Value`

Example:-

```
add(mul(a,add(b,c)),d) + e - sub(f,g)

Output =>

1) mul(a,add(b,c)),d

2) f,g
```

Comment: If you need to handle nested parentheses you should use a parser instead of regex.

Comment: @Lee: Hi.. lee, can you please give me some example?

Comment: in this case you could recursively keep calling that regex on each match till you have no matches.

Comment: You need to use balanced groups, [see this awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406)

Comment: Your regex `\((.*?)\)` matches `(mul(a,add(b,c)`, what are you trying to match?

Comment: @sln he's trying to match the stuff from the "outer" brackets. In PCRE, you could do the following [`\(((?:[^()]|(?R))*)\)`](http://regex101.com/r/vI5lO6)

Comment: @HamZa : thanks for your answer. i need another help, for RegEx like base on particular function name, if(a>b, param(add(c,d)), param(2)); O/P: param(add(c,d)) and param(2)...

Comment: @ThulasiRam lolwut. Please try something before asking and reaching for help. Also, why ask me in the comments? Just post a new question since it's a new "challenge".

Comment: @HamZa : k... sure. i had posted my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396841/how-to-get-text-with-particular-function-name-and-with-nested-parentheses

Answer (score 44, accepted):

.NET allows **recursion** in regular expressions. See [Balancing Group Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

```cs
var input = @"add(mul(a,add(b,c)),d) + e - sub(f,g)";

var regex = new Regex(@"
    \(                    # Match (
    (
        [^()]+            # all chars except ()
        | (?<Level>\()    # or if ( then Level += 1
        | (?<-Level>\))   # or if ) then Level -= 1
    )+                    # Repeat (to go from inside to outside)
    (?(Level)(?!))        # zero-width negative lookahead assertion
    \)                    # Match )",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match c in regex.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Value.Trim('(', ')'));
}
```

Comment: Genious! Excellent answer!

Comment: Calling it recursion seems misleading. It simply uses a stack of captures to keep track of the nesting depth.

Comment: Tried taking your regex expression and put it in here: https://regex101.com/
And it gives an "Incomplete group structure" error. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: @jsirr13 regex101.com does not support .NET regex engine for now. Use linqpad or console app.