# How to get text with particular function name and with nested parentheses ( ) using RegEx?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Reg Expression for Getting Text with particular function name and with nested parentheses, I had tried but i am not getting the RegEx. For this example

**ignore if open or close parentheses between single quotes or double quotes.**

```
eg: strcat("thanks for", param(add(a,b)), ' and ( valuable time ).')

Regex.Matches(script, @"(?x) \( ( (?: [^()]+ | (?<open>\() |
                           (?<-open>\)) )* (?(open)(?!)) ) \)");
```

Example:-

blelow one is the string and function name is **param**,

```
if(a>b, param(add(c,d)), param(2));

Output =>

1) param(add(c,d))

2) param(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\b(?!if)\w+\s*\(.+?\)(?!\)\s*,)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regexr.com?37grl

#### Discussion

You should customize this regex with other reserved keywords that accept parenthesis (`switch` for instance).

```
\b(?!if|switch)\w+\s*\(.+?\)(?!\)\s*,)
```

However, in your case, a [C# parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/81427/363573) is more appropriate.