# Get content between matching outer curly brackets

Tags: regex

OK, so, let's say I have some text like :

```
Any random content here
{{mycontent
more content goes here
{{curly braces may also appear in here}}
{even single ones}

}}

And more content goes here...
```

I need to fetch the part between `{{mycontent` and its corresponding `}}` closing brackets.

How would you go about that, in RegEx (that's a *must*) ?

Comment: What language are you using ? Also what have you tried ?

Comment: @HamZa Well, I'm using PHP, but that's not the point. Btw, I'm already able to achieve what I'm asking in the first place; but in PHP, not in RegEx. Nested patterns always troubled me in Regular Expressions. (I know it may not be tha best approach to the problem, but it *has* to be...)

Comment: Well since you have committed to the community, I'll help you with this one ... [Have fun](http://regex101.com/r/qK6mA7)

Comment: Ah, also the language does matter. Most regex flavors can't do what you want. The above pattern should work in PCRE and Perl. If you want a .NET solution, you might edit [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19694656) to your needs. The first pattern I gave is a slight change of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740).

Comment: @HamZa Let me go through your suggestions and I'll let you know. Unfortunately, my main project is in PHP/CodeIgniter, so using Perl (although possible) would not be preferable... Thanks a lot!

Comment: PS: PHP uses PCRE. So the first pattern should work. Take care

Answer (score -2):

`/\{{2}(.*)\}{2}/s`

This will match anything between 2 curly braces including new lines.

The result would be

```
0 => string '{{mycontent
more content goes here
{{curly braces may also appear in here}}
{even single ones}

}}'
```

Comment: Well, you're just relying on greediness. Something like this would fail `{{ help }} {{ you }}`