# Regex negative look ahead to match markdown links

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

We are stuck over a regex issue.

Here is the problem. Consider the following two patterns:

1) `[hello] [world]`

2) `[hello [world]]`

We need to write a regex able to match only `[world]` in the first one and the entire pattern (`[hello [world]]`) in the second.

By using the negative lookahead, I wrote the following regex which solves part of the problem:

```
\[[^\[\]]+\](?!.*\[[^\[\]]+\])
```

This regex matches pattern 1) as we want, but does not work for pattern 2).

Comment: Which language/tool do you use? Recursion (if supported) is sually the key to matching nested brackets.

Comment: Hi Sebastian and thanks for helping. We are using .NET.

Comment: Make a group with both patterns in it: (pattern|pattern)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text between nested parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693622/how-to-get-text-between-nested-parentheses)

Comment: Actually the words "hello" and "world" are just examples words. The problem is general and the point is being able to handle nested square bracktes in such a scenario.

Comment: Are brackets always balanced?

Comment: Hi @CasimiretHippolyte and thanks for replying. No, the brackets must not be balanced. For instance a pattern like `[Hello world\]]` is a valid text for a markdown link and we should try to support it.

Comment: Something like this: [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5c%5c%5d%2b%7c%5c%5c.%7c%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%5c%5b%7c%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%5d%29*%5d%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%28%3f!%5b%5e%5b%5cn%5d*%5c%5b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5cn%5c%5c%5d%2b%7c%5c%5c.%29*%5d%29&i=%5bhello%5d+%5bworld%5d%0d%0a%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d%0d%0a%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d+%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d+%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d%0d%0a%5bHello+world%5c%5d%5d+%5bHello+world%5c%5d%5d%0d%0a%5bhello%5d+%5bworld%5d+%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d+%5b%5b%5b%5d%0d%0a%5bhello%5d+%5bworld%5d+%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d+%5b+%5b+%5b%0d%0a)

Answer (score 2):

In .NET regex, you may use balanced groups to match nested balanced parentheses. So, to match the last `[...]` substring (with nested parentheses) on a line you need quite a long pattern like

```
\[(?:[^][]+|(?<c>)\[|(?<-c>)])*(?(c)(?!))](?!.*\[(?:[^][]+|(?<d>)\[|(?<-d>)])*(?(d)(?!))])
```

See the [regex demo at RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%5C%5B%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%5D%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%29%29%5D%28%3F!.*%5C%5B%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cd%3E%29%5C%5B%7C%28%3F%3C-d%3E%29%5D%29*%28%3F%28d%29%28%3F!%29%29%5D%29&i=%5Bhello%5D%20%5Bworld%5D%0D%0A%5Bhello%20%5Bworld%5D%5D).

**Details**

- `\[(?:[^][]+|(?<c>)\[|(?<-c>)])*(?(c)(?!))]` - a `[...]` substring with nested brackets:

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `(?:[^][]+|(?<c>)\[|(?<-c>)])*` - zero or more occurrences of:

    - `[^][]+|` - 1 or more chars other than `]` and `[` or
    - `(?<c>)\[|` - empty value added to Group "c" and a `[` is matched
    - `(?<-c>)]` - empty value is subtracted from Group "c" stack and a `]` is matched
  - `(?(c)(?!))` - a conditional that fails the match if Group "c" stack is not empty
  - `]`  - a `]` char
- `(?!.*\[(?:[^][]+|(?<d>)\[|(?<-d>)])*(?(d)(?!))])` - not followed with any 0+ chars other than newline symbols followed with the same pattern as the one above.

Comment: Thanks for quickly replying our question.
We don't know the whole idea of Balanced Group so, at the least, your hint could help us to improve our regex skills.

We are not sure to follow this idea to solve our problem, it seems that it is computational expensive and we need to parse a whole text looking for markdown links in order to replace them. Such a text could be quite long. 

Moreover, it is possible that we have to deal with more complex patterns, such as [Hello [world] or [Hello world]] (scenarios where the number of square brackets is odd.

Comment: Your lookahead is complicated for nothing, to check if there isn't one other balanced group before the end of the string, you only have to check it with `(?![^[]*\[[^]]*])`. You don't need a detailed description.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is not generic enough as it only allows 1 nested level. See [your suggestion demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%5c%5b%7c%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%5d%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%5d%28%3f!.*%28%3f!%5b%5e%5b%5d*%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5d*%5d%29%29&i=%5bhello%5d+%5bworld%5d%0d%0a%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d).

Comment: You don't need to describe other nesting levels in the lookahead. only one suffice as a proof. test it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte when you test your solution, and are sure it works for all the test cases, you may update this wiki answer. I tested and it does not work (see my link above).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: no, you haven't understood, [this is my "suggestion demo"](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%5c%5b%7c%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%5d%29*%5d%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%28%3f!%5b%5e%5b%5cn%5d*%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5cn%5d*%5d%29&i=%5bhello%5d+%5bworld%5d%0d%0a%5bhello+%5bworld%5d%5d)

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here another possible solution to match all markdown links if "correctly" escaped.

Here the regex:

```
\[(?<text>(?:[^\[\]]|\\\[|\\\])+?)\]\((?<link>.+?)\)
```

See [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/XuLqQZ/1).

Note that this not support NOT escaped brackets inside links:

```
[link number \[2]](http://myurl.com)
[link number [2\]](http://myurl.com)
```

It may also not support other edge cases...

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way to find the last balanced square brackets part in a string with the .net regex engine is to search the string from right to left using the `Regex.RightToLeft` property. This way you avoid:

- to search all the string for nothing
- to check the end of the string with a lookahead since the pattern returns the first match on the right.

code:

```
string input = @"[hello] [world] [hello [world\]] ]";
string rtlPattern = @"(?(c)(?!))\[(?>\\.|(?<!\\)[^][]+|(?<-c>)\[|(?<c>)])*]";
Match m;

m = Regex.Match(input, rtlPattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[demo](http://tpcg.io/padkcY)

Note that to well understand what happens you also need to read parts of the pattern from right to left. Details:

```
]  # a literal closing square bracket

(?> # open an atomic group (*)
    \\.         # any escaped character with a backslash
  |
    [^][]+  # all that isn't a square bracket
    (?<!\\) # not preceded by a backslash
  |
    (?<-c>) \[  # decrement the c stack for an opening bracket
  |
    (?<c>)   ]  # increment the c stack for a closing bracket
)* # repeat zero or more times

\[  # a literal square opening bracket

(?(c) # conditional statement: true if c isn't empty
    (?!) # always failing pattern: "not followed by nothing"
)
```

<sub>(*) Note that using an atomic group is mandatory here to avoid an eventual catastrophic backtracking since the group contains an item with a `+` quantifier and is itself repeated. You can learn more about this problem [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).</sub>

This pattern already deals with escaped nested brackets and you can also add the `Regex.Singleline` property if you want to match a part that includes the newline character.