# Match everything inside brackets (nested brackets)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that matches everything inside brackets:

```
 ?\(.*?\)
```

I need adjust this regex, so it also matches nested brackets, for example:

```
ABC ( DEF (GHI) JKL ) MNO
```

Should match **( DEF (GHI) JKL )** in this example

Comment: What are the *expected matches* in the example, please?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Suppose we have an *elaborated example*: `ABC (DEF (GHI) JKL) MNO (PQR) (UV (XYZ)`  what is the answer then? `{(DEF (GHI) JKL)`, `(PQR)}`, {`(DEF (GHI) JKL) MNO (PQR) (UV (XYZ)`}, or something else?

Comment: Do you mean you need to *remove* all substrings inside nested brackets? [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19694656/3832970) should work actually. But there is another one: `while (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\([^()]*\)")) { s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\([^()]*\)", ""); }`

Answer (score 2):

To match the `( DEF (GHI) JKL )` in `ABC ( DEF (GHI) JKL ) MNO` you should change `.*?` to `.*` in your example regex:

```
\(.*\)
```

`.*?` is lazy - it will match shortest possible string;

`.*` is greedy - it will match longest possible string.

Comment: Your answer works perfect! Except one case - "This is ABC (XXX) DEF (XXX) (XXX)". For this string I expect to remove all (XXX) and have this - "This is ABC DEF". But regex also removed "DEF" for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match :

ABC **( DEF (GHI) JKL )** MNO

This works:

```
?\(.*\)
```

Ref: https://regex101.com/r/5Y5ZM0/2

EDIT: Updated with shorter working version from @GameDroids

Comment: in your example, `\(.*\)` this does work too