# Retrieve different groups of values in a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, recursion

I have this following string :

```
((1+2)*(4+3))
```

I would like to get the values exposed with parentheses separately through a Regex. These values must be in a array like string array.

For example :

- Group 1 : ((1+2)*(4+3))
- Group 2 : (1+2)
- Group 3 : (4+3)

I have tried this Regex :

```
(?<content>\(.+\))
```

But she don't functional, because she keeps the group 1

You will have solutions that could allow me to manage this recursively?

Comment: What if you have 7 levels of nested parentheses? You should parse the expression recursively, regex won't help you do that.

Comment: Regex are not suited for deserialization of tree expressions

Comment: Consider using a [LL Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) to transform a mathematical operation string as tree to solve it

Comment: If you know the number of nesting levels (here = 1) you can do it in C# something similar to `\((\([^()]*\)|[^()]+)+\)` since .NET allows you to iterate over captured texts inside a quantified capturing group you'll get the desired results.

Comment: You may use `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)))").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get all overlapping substrings starting with `(` and ending with `)` and having any amount of balanced nested parentheses inside using

```
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)))").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

See the [regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%7C%29%5C%29%29%29&i=%28%281%2B2%29*%284%2B3%29%29).

**Regex details**

The regex is a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) that checks each position within a string and finds a match if its pattern matches. Since the pattern is enclosed with a capturing group (`(...)`) the value is stored in `match.Groups[1]` that you may retrieve once the match is found. `\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)` is a [known pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693622/how-to-get-text-between-nested-parentheses) that matches nested balanced parentheses.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/9y5jl2):

```
var str = "((1+2)*(4+3))";
var pattern = @"(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)))"; 
var result = Regex.Matches(str, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

Output:

```
((1+2)*(4+3))
(1+2)
(4+3)
```