# .Net Regex - Help needed

Tags: .net, regex

### Updated

I need help with a regex that will find the `"@[..[...]]"` pattern.

**I will try to explain.**

A text will contain placeholders which will be replaced with values upon display of that very same text.

A place holder has 3 parts;

- an open tag, starts with "@[" followed by "a dot delimited text" and ends with "[",
- a property list, a "comma separated list" with qouted (double qoutes) values,
- a close tag, "]]".

The property list items can contain one or many placeholders (nested) and both double qoutes (escaped) and brackets.

The regex must overcome the issues with nested placeholders by knowing when it reached the end of the "outer" placeholder as well as any escaped qoutes and brackets.

**Sample**

Consider the following text fragment:

```
Linklist    
@[Link.AppText["[startpage]", "startpage"]]
@[Link.Text["[startpage] loggedin", "The \"@[Text.AppText["startpage"]]\" for users"]]
@[Link.Text["@[Link["startpage"]]", "@[Text.AppText["startpage"]]"]]
```

The match should look like this:

```
match 1  =  @[Link.AppText["[startpage]", "startpage"]]
   Gr.1  =  Link.AppText
   Gr.2  =  "[startpage]", "startpage"

match 2  =  @[Link.Text["[startpage] loggedin", "The \"@[Text.AppText["startpage"]]\" for users"]]
   Gr.1  =  Link.Text
   Gr.2  =  "[startpage] loggedin", "The \"@[Text.AppText["startpage"]]\" for users"

match 3  =  @[Link.Text["@[Link["startpage"]]", "@[Text.AppText["startpage"]]"]]
   Gr.1  =  Link.Text
   Gr.2  =  "@[Link["startpage"]]", "@[Text.AppText["startpage"]]"
```

**With a solution by @ridgerunner I solved it:**

```
@\[([._\w]+)\[([^[\]""]*(?:""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""[^[\]""]*)*)\]\]

@\[                                # Outer open delimiter.
([._\w]+)                          # 1:st group.
\[                                 # Inner open delimiter.
(                                  # Start of 2:nd group.
[^[\]""]*                          # Contents.
(?:""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""    # Contents.
[^[\]""]*)*                        # Contents.
)                                  # End of 2:nd group.
\]\]                               # Close delimiter.
```

**And ... for anyone who looks for a "balanced group solution"**

... after struggling with google search and a lot of regex testing, I finally figured out another working solution, though I had to alter the pattern slightly to make it work: (at least for me :))

```
Regex:  @([._\w]+)\[\[(""(?:[^\[\]]*|\[[^\[]|[^\]]\]|(?<counter>\[\[)|(?<-counter>\]\]))+(?(counter)(?!))"")\]\]

@([._\w]+)\[\[            #   start tag, 1:st group
  (""                     #   start 2:nd group
    (?:                   #   non capturing group
      [^\[\]]*            #   any char but [ or ]
      |                   #   or
      \[[^\[]             #   if [, not followed by a [
      |                   #   or
      [^\]]\]             #   if ], not followed by a ]
      |                   #   or
      (?<counter>\[\[)    #   counter start tag
      |                   #   or
      (?<-counter>\]\])   #   counter stop tag
    )+                    #   end non capturing group
    (?(counter)(?!))      #   if counter <> 0, regex fails
  "")                     #   end 2:nd group
\]\]                      #   end tag
```

Updated placeholders with new pattern; `(@..[[...]]`

```
Linklist
@Link.AppText[["[startpage]", "startpage"]]
@Link.Text[["[startpage] loggedin", "The \"@Text.AppText[["startpage"]]\" for users"]]
@Link.Text[["@Link[["startpage"]]", "@Text.AppText[["startpage"]]"]]
```

Comment: [Very famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: @PellePenna - in case you didn't get the gist from Sriram's link, the point is, don't parse html with regex (you will go nuts).

Comment: Well, in way I did get it, though mine is not about parsing html tags :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Reading this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the quoted portions won't have any escaped chars, this one will do a pretty good job:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"
    # Match @[...[...]...] pattern outside quotes.
    @\[                                # Outer open delimiter.
    [^[\]]*                            # Link text.
    \[                                 # Inner open delimiter.
    [^[\]""]*(?:""[^""]*""[^[\]""]*)*  # Contents.
    \]\]                               # Close delimiter.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Note that if quoted contents *does* contain escaped chars (e.g. `"foo\"bar\"foo"`, or in .NET double-quote syntax: `@"foo""bar""foo"`), the pattern can be modified to handle that too.

Comment: Thanks .. I updated my question but need a fix for escaped chars. If you can help me with that it would be great.

Comment: Could you (or any one) explain this part of the #Contents regex: `"[^[\]"]*`

Comment: @PellePenna - `[^[\]""]*` matches non-quoted portions of the content (zero or more non-square brackets, non-quotes). If a quote is encountered, then the `(?:""[^""]*""[^[\]""]*)*` part kicks in and matches the quoted portion (which may contain square brackets), followed by more non-quoted content.

Comment: Wonderful ... and what do I need to add to be able to have escaped double qoutes within qouted content ?

Comment: @PellePenna - Change: `""[^""]*""` to: `""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""`. (This allows escaped _anything_ inside the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

What does this do ?

```
 #  @"(?-s)@\[([.\w]+)\[""(.*)""\]\]"

 (?-s)
 @\[
 ( [.\w]+ )
 \["
 ( .* )
 "\]\]
```

Comment: As I wrote above, it gives me 1 match with 2 groups, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're looking for. This regex does what you said you wanted. If you want to do nested @'s you have to use Balanced groups. Check out MS web site to find out how. I'd do it for you but I,m a little busy right now.

Comment: As the @'s is nested, I need to find a solution which let me have them nested and as well be able to use the single "double quotes" and "brackets" within the texts ... but of course not combined as in the open/close delimeters

Answer (score 0):

This might help. `outer` group will contain `Link.AppText` part and `inner` group will contain the inner section.

```
@\[(?<outer>[^[]+?)\["(?<Inner>.+)"\]\]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, though it gives the same result as @[([._\w]+)["(.*)"]] but with named groups, which is not what I'm looking for.