# Split String Except When Delimiter In Other Delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

My previous attempt to ask this question was weak and based on the comments I've decided to rewrite it.

I am trying to split a string, but ignore the delimiter in two scenarios... and so far I can only achieve one scenario.

Given this line:

```
string line = "id:2,width:0,bounds{x:1,y:1},screens:[{@subclass:hmm,bounds{x:2,y:2},no:yes}],more:less,less:more";
```

With this expression:

```
Regex.Split(line, @",(?![^{]*})|(?![^[]*})");
```

Will result in

```
id:2
width:0
bounds{x:1,y:1}
screens:[{@subclass:hmm
bounds{x:2,y:2},no:yes}]
more:less
less:more
```

I placed an or operator so that I can grab the character [ but bounds goes to the next line but still keeps no:yes with it which is correct.

I'm unsure as to why screens and bounds is split given the expression above.

Comment: So, what's wrong with your current approach? You have some error or unexpected results?

Comment: what about the test at the end

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I think the main problem is that even given line wouldn't compile :)

Comment: `string[] output = Regex.Split("this, is, a, {hmm, not, sure, about, this}, test", ",(?![^{]*})");`

Comment: Sounds like a job for [balancing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups) :D

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever needs to filter out multiple scenario's in a split expression that has nested characters not to be split, this is the solution:

```
Regex.Split(line, ",(?!([^{]*}|[^[]*]))");
```