# Regex for groups of type 1.2-1.4 or 1.2.3.4-1.3.4.5 or 1.2.3.4.5.6-1.2.3.4.5.7 and so on

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to use this for an ASP.NET validator but the regex expression is what I can't write without first studying a book.

As in the title I want to match something that is of the following format:

```
1.2-4.394

1.33.321.213-2.324.23.545
```

The number of dots (.) increases but it must <s>not</s> be divisible by 2

Comment: `what I can't write without first studing a book.` Please read the example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm looking into it

Comment: It is relatively simple to handle the sequences of digits and dots separately, but the naïve methods of doing so would allow `1.2-3.4.5.6` as valid.  It is much harder to enforce the same number of dotted-numbers on either side of the dash.  On the whole, I'd make the dot counting a validation check after the regex has matched the digits-dot-digits sequences.

Comment: I was about to say the same as Jonathan about the matching of dot-count, if that's a requirement (given your examples it seems to be). Also I'm wondering whether no dots should validate? I'm guessing not but it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: @funkwurm Indeed, no dots should not validate. It is a requirement that the number of dots on either side of the dash  is equal

Comment: Do you intend to do client-side validation? This won't be possible in JavaScript using regexes alone, but .NET regexes can handle it.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I want to use a RegularExpressionValidator for a  column in an GridView. I use it when I'm in edit mode. I think RegularExpressionValidator is server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's kind of tricky because it involves [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799/3764814):

```
^
(?<nb>                       # First series of numbers
  (?:^|(?<=[0-9])\.)         # BOL or dot
  (?>[0-9]+)\.(?>[0-9]+)     # Number pair
)+
-
(?<-nb>                      # Second series of numbers
  (?>[0-9]+)\.(?>[0-9]+)     # Number pair
  (?:$|\.(?=[0-9]))          # EOL or dot
)+
$
(?(nb)(?!))                  # Make sure the second series has the same digit count
```

[Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=049d3378-815c-4ae9-b630-5dffade937d9)

Used with `IgnorePatternWhitespace` for readability, you could also write:

```
^(?<nb>(?:^|(?<=[0-9])\.)(?>[0-9]+)\.(?>[0-9]+))+-(?<-nb>(?>[0-9]+)\.(?>[0-9]+)(?:$|\.(?=[0-9])))+$(?(nb)(?!))
```

This won't be usable from JavaScript though, as JavaScript has very limited regex features. You should set `EnableClientScript` on your `RegularExpressionValidator` to `false`.

Comment: Without look-around: `^(?>[0-9]+)(?<nb>\.(?>[0-9]+))+-(?>[0-9]+)(?<-nb>\.(?>[0-9]+))+$(?(nb)(?!))`. Your second regex seems to have duplicated `<nb>` part at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, this regex works nice! Do you know how could I add the test that the number of dots on left or right side be not divisibile by 2 ? there must alway be at least 1 dot

Comment: @UrsulRosu oops I totally missed that part, sorry. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

And when it's not possible to use ASP.NET magical Regex, and with dots not be divisible by 2 You can do that:

```
^(?:\d+\.\d+-\d+\.\d+|(?:\d+\.){2}\d+\.\d+-(?:\d+\.){2}\d+\.\d+|(?:\d+\.){4}\d+\.\d+-(?:\d+\.){4}\d+\.\d+|(?:\d+\.){6}\d+\.\d+-(?:\d+\.){6}\d+\.\d+|(?:\d+\.){8}\d+\.\d+-(?:\d+\.){8}\d+\.\d+)$
```

But that work only for 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 dots (before and after the -)...

Test: [here](http://regex101.com/r/oP4kX8/1)