# Brackets with dot, regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I want delete brakets that ends on a dot from string. I use regular expresion - `@"\([^)]+\)\."`
it works with string like this - `some text (some text) some (text).`, after regular expression I have string - `some text (some text) some` 
But this not work with string like that - `some text (some text) some (text (text) some).`
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your regex like below to match the brackets which ends with `.`

```
@"\((?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\)\."
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uN0eP5/1)

**Regular Expression:**

```
\(                       '('
(?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                         times):
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                           more times)
  \(                       '('
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                           more times)
  \)                       ')'
)*                       end of grouping
[^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more
                         times)
\)                       ')'
\.                       '.'
```

Answer (score 3):

*"How to fix it?"* Traditional answer: You can't. Regular expressions do not support rested constructs. This is true for most regex dialects out there.

---

The .NET regular expression engine however supports *balancing groups*. With them you can identify and handle nesting.

To handle a nested construct, you must define its opening and closing pattern, in your case those are the parentheses `(` and `)`, respectively.

- open: `(?<paren>\()`
- close: `(?<-paren>\))`

Think of this as a sort of counter named "paren" that counts up when it encounters `(` and counts down when it encounters `)` (internally, it's a bit different, but as a metaphor this is sufficient).

Now those two can be used to define the contents of a parenthesis, i.e

- either anything but a parenthesis: `[^()]*`
- or the opening pattern
- or closing pattern from above

or, in one expression: `(?:[^()]*|(?<paren>\()|(?<-paren>\)))+`

The entire regex should fail when the counter is not zero at the end, i.e. the parentheses are not balanced. To make that happen, the `(?(paren)(?!))` construct is used (that's a *conditional*, designed to fail when there is an unmatched `paren` left).

Your finished expression looks like this (whitespace ignored)

```
\(
  (?:
    [^()]*
    |(?<paren>\()
    |(?<-paren>\))
  )+
  (?(paren)(?!))
\)\.$
```

See it live: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=feb992a2-cc5d-497a-9d4a-a10317487e46

Recommended reading:

- [What are regular expression Balancing Groups? here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups) **(go read it, it's fantastic)**
- [MSDN: Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition)
- [regular-expressions.info: Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)
- [Flagrant Badassery: Fun With .NET Regex Balancing Groups](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups)
- [MSDN Blogs: Nested/Recursive Regex and .NET Balancing Groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timart/archive/2013/05/14/nested-recursive-regex-and-net-balancing-groups-detect-a-function-with-a-regex.aspx)

Comment: thks a lot, very intresting method