# RegEx to match nested parentheses including the start and end parentheses

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
string st = "this (a,b) and this (s,(r,t),u) is a test";
var regex = new Regex(@"\(([^()]+| (?<Level>\()| (?<-Level>\)))+(?(Level)(?!))\)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match c in regex.Matches(input))
{
  Console.WriteLine(c.Value.Trim('(', ')'));
}
```

The above C# code in .NET 4.5 correctly returns:

```
a,b
s,(r,t),u
```

But I need the output including the parentheses as:

```
(a,b)
(s,(r,t),u)
```

Comment: You can't do this with regex. You can use regex in a greedy or lazy way, but  you can't apply logic to handle balancing of parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you currently have the output of:

```
a,b
s,(r,t),u
```

Since you are using `Trim('(', ')')` it removes the outer parentheses — to include them use:

```
Console.WriteLine(c.Value)
```

**Result:**

```
(a,b)
(s,(r,t),u)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with regex.

You can use regex in a greedy or lazy way, but  you can't apply logic to handle balancing of parentheses.

If you use `\(.*\)` you will capture everything (greedy) from the first to the last parentheses and if you use `\(.*?\)` (lazy or ungreedy) you will match from the first to the second one. Regex is no the right tool to match embedded strings (that's why they are also a bad idea to match embedded xhtml tags).

Imho, you should use a simple balance algorithm in a for loop. However, if you still want to use regex you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups).

Comment: I agree that one can use a balance algorithm in a "for" loop to achieve the same. In my case a RegEx with .NET Regular Expressions Balancing Groups also works.