# Using regex on a specific setup

Tags: c#, regex

I know a bit about regular expressions, but far from enough to figure out this one.

I have tried to see if I could find something that could help me, but I got a hard time understanding how to construct the REGEX expression in c#.

Here is what I need.If I have a string like the following.

string s = "this is (a (string))"

What I need is to focus on the parentheses.

I want to be able to split this string up into the following List/Array "parts".

1) "this", "is", "a (string)"

or

2) "this", "is", "(a (string))".

would both like how to do it with 1) and 2). Anyone got an idea of how to solve this problem?

Can this be solved using REGEX? Anyone knows a good guide to learn about it?

Hope someone can help.

Greetings.

Comment: If you say you know a bit of a regex, what have you tried? And please be precise with what you need to obtain as a result.

Comment: Regular expressions don't work well with nested constructs like this.

Comment: I don't know much about regex. I know about regular expressions a bit in general.

Comment: "Regular expressions don't work well with nested constructs like this." Okay? Any suggest of what to look at then?

Comment: @ANACoder You'll have to parse the string yourself.  Loop through the characters and keep track of the parenthesis depth.  But it really depends on which of the two outcomes you want and maybe on what should happen if there is more nesting than what you have shown.

Comment: If you are looking for a regex solution, here it is: [`\(((?>[^()]+|\((?<o>)|\)(?<-o>))*(?(o)(?!)))\)|\S+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c(((%3f%3e%5b%5e()%5d%2b%7c%5c((%3f%3co%3e)%7c%5c)(%3f%3c-o%3e))*(%3f(o)(%3f!)))%5c)%7c%5cS%2b&i=this+is+(a+(string))).

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/tln9mG).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to *split* with some kind of *escape* (do not count for space if it's within parentheses) you
can easily implement something like this, *easy loop* without *regular expressions*:

```
private static IEnumerable<String> SplitWithEscape(String source) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    yield break;

  int escapeCount = 0;
  int start = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) {
    char ch = source[i];

    if (escapeCount > 0) {
      if (ch == '(')
        escapeCount += 1;
      else if (ch == ')')
        escapeCount -= 1;
    }
    else {
      if (ch == ' ') {
        yield return source.Substring(start, i - start);

        start = i;
      }
      else if (ch == '(')
        escapeCount += 1;
    }
  }

  if ((start < source.Length - 1) && (escapeCount == 0))
    yield return source.Substring(start);
}


....

String source = "this is (a (string))";
String[] split = SplitWithEscape(source).ToArray();
Console.Write(String.Join("; ", split));
```

Comment: Ty so much. This seems to solve it in the best way. Exactly what I needed. Ty so much again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
([^\(\s]+)\s+([^\(\s]+)\s+\((.*)\)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH4hF0/2)

But this will only match with fixed number of words in your input string, in this case, two words before the parentheses. The final regex will depend on what are your specifications.

Answer (score 1):

.NET regex supports balanced constructs. Thus, you can always safely use .NET regex to match substrings between a balanced number of delimiters that may have something inside them.

So, you can use

```
\(((?>[^()]+|\((?<o>)|\)(?<-o>))*(?(o)(?!)))\)|\S+
```

to match parenthesized substrings (while capturing the contents in-between parentheses into Group 1) or match all non-whitespace chunks (`\S+` matches 1+ non-whitespace symbols).

See [*Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2), [*Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) or [*What are regular expression Balancing Groups?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups) for more details on how balancing groups work.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C(((%3F%3E%5B%5E()%5D%2B%7C%5C((%3F%3Co%3E)%7C%5C)(%3F%3C-o%3E))*(%3F(o)(%3F!)))%5C)%7C%5CS%2B&i=this%20is%20(a%20(string)))

If you need to extract all the match values and captured values, you need to get all matched groups that are not empty or whitespace. So, use [this C# code](http://ideone.com/tln9mG):

```
var line = "this is (a (string))";
var pattern = @"\(((?>[^()]+|\((?<o>)|\)(?<-o>))*(?(o)(?!)))\)|\S+";
var result = Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(x => x.Groups.Cast<Group>()
            .Where(m => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Value))
            .Select(t => t.Value))
        .ToList();
foreach (var s in result) // DEMO
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Ty so much for this answer as well. Will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `((?<=\()[^}]*(?=\)))|\W+` to split in words and then get the content in the group 1...
See this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/aH4hF0/3)