# Replace anchor tag value with anchor title if href value is empty by regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace the anchor tag value with anchor's title value if any anchor tag's href attribute is blank.

Like

```
<a xlink:href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry<a xlink:href ="http://google.com">Google</a>.
```

if I try with below regex:

```
<a [^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>
```

DEMO http://regexr.com/3h6on

then output I am getting below

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Google.
```

it replaced both anchor tag with Anchor Text value, and I need to replace those anchor tag where the href attribute value is empty.

I need an output like below

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry<a xlink:href ="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: Will this help? `<a xlink:href=\"\">(.*?)<\/a>`

Comment: Nope @ramesh I have also added the regex test link, thanks for help

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/2064981

Comment: @PriyankGupta - the sample in your question has double quote whereas the regexr had only single quotes. for single quotes try `<a xlink:href=\'\'>(.*?)<\/a>`

Comment: why not use the html agility pack - much more reliable way to do it. http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach looks rather messy but for the test link you provided it seems to work just like you want it to:

```
<a [^>]+?(?=href=(?:"|')(?:"|'))[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

[Try it with this link.](https://regexr.com/3h6q7)

---

What I've added to the regex is the following part

```
[^>]+?(?=href=(?:"|')(?:"|'))[^>]*?
```

The . wildcards at the beginning and end of the part I've added are just there to match with any additional attributes or whitespaces between the < >.

The regex inside the parenthesis is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). This means that it will match whatever is inside the parenthesis but will not include it into the results.

The positive lookahead matches an href followed by an empty string.

*Note that my regex still matches if the quotation marks after the href= expression do not match*

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: I tested this my original sting but it selects the string from first to last anchor link.

Comment: @PriyankGupta Strange - for me it works just like you wanted it to work: https://regexr.com/3h6oq

Comment: yaa @neel it work in this scenario but does not work in my case see this link http://regexr.com/3h6pc

Comment: @PriyankGupta corrected my answer to work with the case you provided: https://regexr.com/3h6q7

Comment: Thanks, @Neele for helping out on this, your update resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: `<a[^<]+href=(['"]{2})\1?[^>]*?>([^<>]*)<\/a>`

[Try it here](https://regexr.com/3h6qv).