# Regex.Matches to get substrings between <>: I need add ( and ) also as substring in the result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.7.1 and Visual Studio 2017.

I have to split these three strings:

```
"<expr><op><expr>"
"(<expr><op><expr>)"
"<pre_op>(<expr>)"
```

into

```
string[] { "<expr>", "<op>", "<expr>" }
string[] { "(", "<expr>", "<op>", "<expr>", ")"}
string[] { "<pre_op>", "(", "<expr>", ")" }
```

The following sentence works fine, but it doesn't handle `(` or `)`:

```
string[] result1 = Regex
    .Matches("<expr><op><expr>", @"<.*?>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
string[] result2 = Regex
    .Matches("(<expr><op><expr>)", @"<.*?>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

But result1 and result2 are equal?

How can I handle `(` and `)` to get them as substrings also?

Comment: You want to make your regex ungreedy.  Or else it will grab between `()` without finding matches in between.

Comment: How about `[(]|<.*?>|[)]` maybe?

Comment: @chrisz Thanks. I will look for what ungreedy means (and some examples). Thanks, again.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Thanks!!! I was testing with `(|)|<.*?>`.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange or maybe `[()]|<[^<>]*>`?

Comment: @revo Yep I like yours better for the first character group (`[()]`), not sure about `[^<>]` though. Not quite sure about performance, but to me `<.*?>` is more readable.

Comment: Without any details on specs, even `@"<.*?>|."` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] result1 = Regex
    .Matches("<expr><op><expr>", **@"(\(|<.*?>|\))"**)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
            string[] result2 = Regex
                .Matches("(<expr><op><expr>)", @"(\(|<.*?>|\))")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToArray();
            string[] result3 = Regex
                .Matches("<pre_op>(<expr>)", @"(\(|<.*?>|\))")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is arguably a nice use case for [.NET balancing groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#balancing) to ensure all round and angle brackets are balanced, see also [What are regular expression Balancing Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups)

The first pattern does just that

```
(?<B>\()+[^()]+(?<-B>\))(?(B)(?!))|(?<A><)+[^<>]+(?<-A>>)+(?(A)(?!))
```

matching `<tags>` and `(everything between brackets)`
The second regex then is used to tokenize the perfectly balanced parts.

```
\(|<.*?>|\)
```

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"<expr><op><expr>
(<expr><op><expr>)
<pre_op>(<expr>)
(<expr>)<pre_op>(<expr>)";

         Regex rxBalanced = new Regex(
            @"(?<B>\()+[^()]+(?<-B>\))(?(B)(?!))|(?<A><)+[^<>]+(?<-A>>)+(?(A)(?!))",
            RegexOptions.Multiline
            | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
            | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
            | RegexOptions.Compiled
        );
        Regex rxTokens = new Regex(
            @"\(|<.*?>|\)",
            RegexOptions.Multiline
            | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
            | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
            | RegexOptions.Compiled
        );

        foreach (Match match in rxBalanced.Matches(input))
        {
            foreach (Match token in rxTokens.Matches(match.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(token.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

An alternative pattern that would allow you to check both balancing groups at the same time could look like this

```
(?<B>(\())*((?<A><)+[^<>]+(?<-A>>)+(?(A)(?!)))+(?<-B>(\)))*(?(B)(?!))
```

Unfortunately, it's much harder to get all the needed values from the resulting nested collection. However, I found this problem interesting enough to create a LinQ-query that does all the black magic:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<B>(\\())*((?<A><)+[^<>]+(?<-A>>)+(?(A)(?!)))+(?<-B>(\\)))*(?(B)(?!))",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var x = (from Match m in regex.Matches("(<x><y><z>)<expr>(<a><b><c>)<d>")
        select new
        {
            result = m.Groups[1].Value.StartsWith("(") ?
                        (new List<string> { "(" }
                            .Concat(m.Groups[2].Captures.Count > 1 ?
                                (from Capture c in m.Groups[2].Captures select c.Value).ToList()
                                : new List<string> { m.Groups[2].Value }
                            )
                            .Concat(new List<string> { ")" })
                        )
                        : new List<string> { m.Value }
        }).SelectMany(r => r.result);
```