# Regex for capturing remainder of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regex:

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex( @"(?:\s+(?<statement>(?:[\w./]+)?\s*(?:(?:With|Without)\s*(?:[\w./]+))?)\s*(?:$|\s+AND))+(?<remainder>.*)");
```

For the string " *Tom With Jane AND Mike Without Anne AND*" I can capture both "*Tom With Jane*" and "*Mike Without Anne*" as statements. Now I'd like to capture the last "AND" in the "remainder" group  since it is not followed by another statement. How can I do that? Here's the code that I'm using:

```
class Program {
public static Regex regex = new Regex( @"(?:\s+(?<statement>(?:[\w./]+)?\s*(?:(?:With|Without)\s*(?:[\w./]+))?)\s*(?:$|\s+AND))+(?<remainder>.*)" );
static void Main( string[] args ) {
  var s = " Tom With Jane AND Mike Without Anne AND";
  var match = regex.Match( s );
  var statements = match.Groups["statement"];
  var remainder = match.Groups["remainder"];
}
```

}

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There's a space at the beggining of the string - this is intended

Comment: Are you using regex.split?

Comment: You need to do better, i have no idea what you are asking and possibly just about everyone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's maybe a bit fancy but I think using [.NET Balancing Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups) ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition)) allows to create a clean solution that is easy to extend:

```
(?<statement>(?<word>\w+)+\s+(With|Without)\s+(?<-word>\w+)+(?(word)(?!)))|(?<statement>\sAND\s)|(?<remainder>\sAND$)
```

[**Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/diiym2)

You can test the pattern online at [regexstorm.net/tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split the string using `\s*AND\s*`?

```
string s = " Tom With Jane AND Mike Without Anne AND";
string[] ss = Regex.Split(s.Trim(), @"\s*AND\s*");
```

will give you

```
new string[] { "Tom With Jane", "Mike Without Anne", "" }
```

If you want to avoid matching names that contain "AND" and still match  "AND"s at the end of string, you could add a word-boundary constraint: `\s*\bAND\b\s*`.