# Regex counting characters on two sides

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not entirely sure if the title makes any sense at all but I'm not sure how to explain any better. I'm trying to match a string that starts with one or more `(`'s and ends with the same amount of `)`'s. I've tried many different things but I can't figure out how to do this in regex, or if it's possible at all! Can anyone send me in the right direction?

**Examples**

Match: `(a)`

Match: `((a))`

Don't match: `((a)`

Don't match: `((a)))`

etc etc etc, you get the point.

Comment: Please tag the language you're implementing in

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks, will do

Comment: This is not something that should be done with regex. Regex is really bad at counting.

Comment: @Aran-Fey But is it possible? And if so, would it have a big effect on performance? Otherwise I might have to add validation in C#

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible in most regex flavors, but I don't remember how. It requires some god-tier regex skill.

Comment: Why *must* you use a Regex for this? What will you be doing after you match or don't match the characters?

Comment: You may, [`^(?>(?<o>\()+.*?(?<-o>\))+)$(?(o)(?!))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3co%3e%5c%28%29%2b.*%3f%28%3f%3c-o%3e%5c%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%29%24%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29&i=%28a%29%0d%0a%28%28a%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%28%28a%29%0d%0a%28%28a%29%29%29&o=m), but you do not have to. If there must be no `(` and `)` inside the string, [`^(?>(?<o>\()+[^()]*(?<-o>\))+)$(?(o)(?!))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3co%3e%5c%28%29%2b%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%28%3f%3c-o%3e%5c%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%29%24%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29&i=%28a%29%0d%0a%28%28a%29%29%0d%0a%28%28a%29&o=m).

Comment: @DourHighArch Not _must_, I could do it in C# aswell, but I would have liked to have a slightly more complete regular expression. (I'm making a regex to match static js variables, and their values can be wrapped in parenthesis)

Comment: Wait, are you trying to “count characters on two sides” or are you “making a regex to match static js variables” because those are two completely different problems.

Comment: @DourHighArch I know they are, but I'm only having trouble with figuring out of there's an equal amount of parenthesis on both sides of the value, which makes my problem "counting characters on two sides"

Comment: Does `^\((?:[^()]|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+(?(open)(?!))\)$` work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks like it's what I need, thanks! Do you happen to know what I should Google to actually understand what the `(?<-o>)` part means? I'd love to learn how it works (edit: this was a reply to your previous comment)

Comment: Does the last one work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yup! That one does indeed work aswell. Thanks :) My question about what that `-open` group is called remains though haha

Comment: Ok, that means the question is indeed a dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll hit the "that solved my question!" button, thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Here is [another post that will help you dive into balanced constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups/17004406#17004406).

Comment: Woah @WiktorStribiżew I just read through that and understand how it works now! Thanks :) that's super interesting & clever

Comment: I figured it out how to do it without fancy C# features; all you need are lookarounds: `^(?:\((?=.*((?(1)\1|)\))$))+(?!\().*(?<!\))\1$`. Basically, it matches 1 character at a time, and for each consumed opening brace it also captures an additional closing brace in a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, relatively easily, with a stack data structure. You process the string character by character, and you push when you meet `(` and pop when you meet `)`. If at the end of the string processing you have arrived with empty stack than the string is valid. Otherwise, if you meet ')' with empty stack then the string is not valid.

To count, just maintain a variable of the maximum size that the stack will reach.