# Java, can't get Regular Expression to work

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I saw the following regex online and wanted to implement it into my Java Application (using java.util.regex).

```
(?<=(<Anhang>))(\w|\d|\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\]"'+–/\/®°⁰!?{}|`~]| )+?(?=(<\/Anhang>))
```

This is supposed to match anything enclosed in `'<Anhang>'`.

It works fine in a JavaScript engine but I can't get it to work in Java.

Here I tested it with a JavaScript engine on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) against this text:

```
BLALBLA BLA BLA <Anhang> 
gonegone gone gone ,os .psd
</Anhang> ajdajadw
```

Which produced the following result:

[image]

So I went ahead and tried to use it in "[Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)" but it either didn't match the Text or there was a Syntax error.
I know that I have to escape certain characters but I just didn't get it to work, here is what I tried:

```
(?<=(<Anhang>))(\\w|\\d|\\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\\]\"'+–/"/®°⁰!?{}|`~]| )+?(?=(<\"Anhang>))

(?<=(<Anhang>))(\\w|\\d|\\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\\]\"'+–/"/®°⁰!?\{\}|`~]| )+?(?=(<\"Anhang>))

(?<=(<Anhang>))(\\w|\\d|\\n|[().,\\\\-:;@#$%^&*\[\\]\"'+–/"/®°⁰!?\{\}|`~]| )+?(?=(<\"Anhang>))
```

Comment: Have you tried `(?<=(<Anhang>))(\\w|\\d|\\n|[().,\\-:;@#$%^&*\\[\\]\"\'+–/\/®°⁰!?{}|\`~]| )+?(?=(<\/Anhang>))`?

Comment: I did, "Unable to execute regular expression. java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 36"

Comment: There is no formal, standardize regex language. Rather, it's a loosely grouped class of languages that vary from one engine to another. Even within a single parent language, like Java, your regex will depend on the actual library that you're using. For example, some regex engines have no support for [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Others require a lookaround to be fixed-width, while others have no such restriction. .NET has [balanced groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799), which few other engines have. Etc.

Comment: Although in this case I'd guess that you didn't sufficiently escape the slashes: `\[\\]\"` should probably be `\\[\\]\"`

Comment: Also, `(?=(<\"Anhang>))` should probably be `(?=(</Anhang>))`

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification, I added information regarding the implemented Java Library

Comment: You should probably take a look at [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) and [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166). Also on this mandatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is overcomplicated, and appears to be malformed as well.  It looks like you just want the text between the `<Anhang>` tags, so maybe try something simpler, like this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*<Anhang>(.+?)</Anhang>.*", Pattern.DOTALL);

String s = "BLALBLA BLA BLA <Anhang> \n" +
           "gonegone gone gone ,os .psd\n" +
           "</Anhang> ajdajadw";

Matcher m = regex.matcher(s);

if (m.matches()) {
    String capturedGroup = m.group(); // This is the text inside the tags
}
```

Creating a Pattern and specifying `Pattern.DOTALL` instead of using `String.matches()` is important, as it allows the `.` to match newline characters.

**However**, I think it's worth mentioning that regex is generally the wrong tool to use to parse XML or HTML.  There are custom parsing libraries for that, which I suggest you look into.  It avoids the risk of a "works in 99% of the cases" regex causing bugs in your code.

Comment: OR don't use regex at all. If you have HTML use HTML parser instead. BTW why `.*` at start and end of regex? Simply use `find()` instead of `matches()` and regex will not be forced to match entire text.

Comment: @Pshemo The `.*` is necessary because of the additional text before and after the tags.  But I agree that using an actual XML/HTML parser is usually a better approach. It might be overkill if this is just a simple one-off exercise, but it's definitely worth bringing up the fact that HTML cannot actually be fully validated via regex.

Comment: `.*` is only necessary when we use `.matches()` which requires from regex to match *entire* text. If we use `.find()` instead, regex engine will be checking if it regex pattern can be matched even in *part* of text, which eliminates need for surrounding regex with `.*`.