# Regex split by comma not inside parenthesis (.NET)

Tags: .net, regex

I need to split text (sql query) by each comma which is not between parenthesis.

Example (I marked commas which should be included in split):

```
a."Id",                //<- this comma
a."Description",       //<- this comma
UJsonObject(
   fepv."Id",          //<- NOT this comma
   fepv."SystemName",  //<- NOT this comma
   string_agg(
        translations."Translations", ',' //<- NOT this comma (here can be some nested parenthesis also)
   ) as "Translations"
) as "Translations",   //<- this comma
b."DataSource",        //<- this comma
a."Name",              //<- this comma
a."Value"
```

I found universal solution here: https://regex101.com/r/6lQKjP/2 but it appears that this solution is not working in dotnet.

I would like to use Regex.Split, but if this case can be satisfied by Regex.Matches I will be happy too. Also I know I can write my own parser, but I read that simple cases (which not extract nested parenthesis) can be handled via Regex.

Comment: You cannot "convert" the PCRE regex to .NET because .NET does not  support skipping after faailing a match. You need to completely re-write this, use another approach. E.g., `var s  = Regex.Replace(text, @"\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)|(,)", m=>m.Groups[1].Success ? "___temp___" : m.Value)` and then `var results = s.Split("___temp___");`

Comment: Why is https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/336123-skip-commas-in-brackets-regexp a universal solution? It looks like some workaround thatdoes not even do what is asked for. `\w+(\([^)]+\))?` simply matches 1+ word chars and an optional `(...)` substring that has no `)`  inside.

Comment: Maybe but I tested it and works for me. Universal - I mean works with any sql expression and it not depends on syntax I use. In each case it selects correct commas.

Comment: So, if it works for you - why ask a question? `\w+(\([^)]+\))?` is a valid .NET regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because I need this to work in dotnet I as wrote in question.

Comment: It [works in .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b%28%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d%2b%5c%29%29%3f&i=a.%22Id%22%2c%0d%0aa.%22Description%22%2c%0d%0aUJsonObject%28%0d%0a+++fepv.%22Id%22%2c%0d%0a+++fepv.%22SystemName%22%2c%0d%0a+++string_agg%28%0d%0a++++++++translations.%22Translations%22%2c+%27%2c%27+%2f%2f%3c-+NOT+this+comma+%28here+can+be+some+nested+parenthesis+also%29%0d%0a+++%29+as+%22Translations%22%0d%0a%29+as+%22Translations%22%2c%0d%0ab.%22DataSource%22%2c%0d%0aa.%22Name%22%2c%0d%0aa.%22Value%22),  but I can't see how it can work for you.

Comment: The `UJsonObject(....` matches up to the first `)`, not to the corresponding closing `)`.

Comment: There is some bug in my question. Worked example should navigate to regex101 not to mathworks. Sorry for misunderstanding. I updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/6lQKjP/2) - `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|,` - uses recursion, .NET does not support it, but there is a way to do the same thing using balancing construct. The From the PCRE verbs - `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` - only `(*FAIL)` can be written as `(?!)` (it causes an unconditional fail at the place where it stands), .NET does not support skipping a match at a specific position and resuming search from that failed position.

I suggest replacing all commas that are not inside nested parentheses with some temporary value, and then splitting the string with that value:

```
var s = Regex.Replace(text, @"\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)|(,)", m =>
     m.Groups[1].Success ? "___temp___" : m.Value);
var results = s.Split("___temp___");
```

**Details**

- `\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)` - a pattern that matches nested parentheses:

  - `\(`  - a `(` char
  - `(?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*` - 0 or more occurrences of

    - `[^()]+|` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or
    - `(?<o>)\(|` - a `(` and a value is pushed on to the Group "o" stack
    - `(?<-o>)\)` -  a `)` and a value is popped from the Group "o" stack
  - `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional construct that fails the match if Group "o" stack is not empty
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `(,)` - Group 1: a comma

Only the comma captured in Group 1 is replaced with a temp substring since the `m.Groups[1].Success` check is performed in the match evaluator part.

Answer (score 1):

You can match your tokens in a single pass using a .NET regular expression [Balancing Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799/7586):

```
(?>
    (?<S>\()      # if you see an open parentheses, push it to the stack
    |
    (?<-S>\))     # match a closing parentheses when the stack has a paired open parentheses
    |
    [^,()]        # match any character except parentheses or commas
    |
    (?(S),|(?!))  # if we're already inside parentheses, we're allowed to match a comma
)+
(?(S)(?!))    # at the end, make sure there are no extra open parentheses we didn't close.
```

You can get the tokens as:

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                   .Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

[Working example in Sharp Labs](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

This approach is a bit complicated, but the syntax it supports can be expanded without too much trouble. For example, we can add support for `-- single line SQL comments` comments and `'SQL strings'`:

```
(?>
    (?<S>\()
    |
    (?<-S>\))
    |
    --.*                 # match from "--" to the end of the line
    |
    '[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'  # match SQL string, single quote, escaped by two single quotes
    |
    [^,()]
    |
    (?(S),|(?!))
)+
(?(S)(?!))
```

[Working example](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Answer (score 0):

Please regard this as an extended comment. In pseudo-code, the commas not enclosed in parentheses can be identified as follows:

```
commas = []
n = 0
for each index i of string
   c = char at index i of string
   if c == '('
     increase n by 1
   elsif c == ')'
     decrease n by 1 if n > 0, else raise unbalanced parens exception
   elsif c == ','
     add i to commas if n equals 0
   end
end
raise unbalanced parens exception if n > 0
```

The array `comma` will contain the indices of the commas on which the string is to be split. Splitting the string at given indices is straightforward.

The variable `n` equals the number of left parentheses that are not yet matched by a right parentheses. The code also confirms that the parentheses are balanced.

Comment: This was my first solution. If none of regular expression was working then I will still using this algorithm.

Comment: Considering that this approach is straightforward and undoubtedly faster than the use of a regular expression, why would you prefer the latter?