# How to remove JSON text (including CRLF's) inside delimited records in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Have a strange issue where I need to remove JSON text in a tilde delimited file (having the JSON breaks the import due to CRLF at the end of each line of the JSON). Example line:

```
Test Plan Work~Response Status: BadRequest Bad Request,Response Content: {
  "trace": "0HM5285F2",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "server_error",
      "message": "Couldn't access service ",
      "moreInfoUrl": null,
      "target": {
        "type": null,
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ]
},Request: https://www.test.com Headers: Accept: application/json
SubscriberId: 
~87c5de00-5906-4d2d-b65f-4asdfsdfsdfa29~3/17/2020 1:54:08 PM
```

or ones like these that don't have JSON but still have the same pattern I need:

```
Test Plan Pay Work~Response Status: InternalServerError Internal Server Error,Response Content: Error,Request: https://api.test.com Headers: Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5c
SubscriberId: eb7aee
~9d05b16e-e57b-44be-b028-b6ddsdfsdf62a5~1/20/2021 7:07:53 PM
```

Need both of these types of CSV text to be in the format:

```
Test Plan Work~Response Status: BadRequest Bad Request~87c5de00-5906-4d2d-b65f-4asdfsdfsdfa29~3/17/2020 1:54:08 PM
```

The JSON (including the CRLF's at the end of each line of the JSON) are breaking the import of the data into Powershell. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell (or rather, **.NET**) has two perculiar features in its regex engine that might be perfect for this use case - [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups) and [conditionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#conditional-matching-based-on-a-valid-captured-group)!

Balancing groups is a complicated feature to fully explain, but it essentially allows us to "keep count" of occurrences of specific named subexpressions in a regex pattern, and looks like this when applied:

```
PS ~> $string = 'Here is text { but wait { it has } nested { blocks }} here is more text'
PS ~> $string -replace '\{(?>\{(?<depth>)|[^{}]+|\}(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\}'
Here is text  here is more text
```

Let's break down the regex pattern:

```
\{                    # match literal '{'
(?>                   # begin atomic group* 
     \{(?<depth>)     #     match literal '{' and increment counter
  |  [^{}]+           #  OR match any sequence of characters that are NOT '{' or '}'
  |  \}(?<-depth>)    #  OR match literal '}' and decrement counter
)*                    # end atomic group, whole group should match 0 or more times
(?                    # begin conditional group*
    (depth)(?!)       # if the 'depth' counter > 0, then FAIL!
)                     # end conditional group
\}                    # match literal '}' (corresponding to the initial '{')
```

*) The `(?>...)` [atomic grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#atomic-groups) prevents backtracking - a safeguard against accidentally counting anything more than once.

For the CRLF characters in the remaining fields, we can prefix the pattern with `(?s)` - this makes the regex engine include new lines when matching the `.` "any" metacharacter, up until we reach the position just before `~87c5...`:

```regex
(?s),Response Content:\s*\{(?>\{(?<depth>)|[^{}]+|\}(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\}.*?(?=~)
```

Or we can, perhaps more accurately, describe the fields following the JSON as repeating pairs of `,` and "not `,`":

```regex
,Response Content:\s*(?:\{(?>\{(?<depth>)|[^{}]+|\}(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\})?\s*(?:,[^,]+?)*(?=~)
```

Let's give it a try against your multi-line input string:

```
$string = @'
Test Plan Work~Response Status: BadRequest Bad Request,Response Content: {
  "trace": "0HM5285F2",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "server_error",
      "message": "Couldn't access service ",
      "moreInfoUrl": null,
      "target": {
        "type": null,
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ]
},Request: https://www.test.com Headers: Accept: application/json
SubscriberId: 
~87c5de00-5906-4d2d-b65f-4asdfsdfsdfa29~3/17/2020 1:54:08 PM
'@
$string -replace ',Response Content:\s*(?:\{(?>\{(?<depth>)|[^{}]+|\}(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))\})?\s*(?:,[^,]+?)*(?=~)'
```

Output:

```
Test Plan Work~Response Status: BadRequest Bad Request~87c5de00-5906-4d2d-b65f-4asdfsdfsdfa29~3/17/2020 1:54:08 PM
```

Comment: @JackBlack Make the whole JSON subexpression "optional" by wrapping it in a grouping construct and add the `?` quantifier at the end (I've updated the last example)

Comment: @JackBlack add the sample [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66552720/edit), comments are not really fit for exchange code or data :-)

Comment: Good point, sorry about that,.,added above. Very new to this :)

Comment: Added an example of what I was asking in original question. The original regex works great on the JSON sections but misses the ones with HTML. I am still looking to negate everything between the same items as originally. THis must be so close...Thanks for your assistance so far!

Comment: @MathiasRJessen Any other suggestions to include the additional scenario above? This regex stuff is currently out of my league but trying to work through it... really appreciate any input!