# How return contents of method in txt file

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to write a regular expression to return the method contents between method name and the following method name.  I'll further parse that for info I'm extracting.  How do I do that?  So far I have it working to get the info from the method name on, but don't know how to get it to stop at the following method name.  Any other ideas would be appreciated.

This returns the line**s** that match string method name (but I want entire method):

```
$contents = Get-Content $codePath | Select-String -Pattern "$methodNameToReturn.*" -AllMatches
```

This is where I'm trying to get it to end the string returned at the following method, but it's not finding anything:

```
Get-MethodContents -codePath $File[0] -methodNameToReturn "GetStatusFromCode" -followingMethodName "SkipPage"

Function Get-MethodContents{
[cmdletbinding()]
Param ( [string]$codePath, [string]$methodNameToReturn, [string]$followingMethodName)
Process
{
    $contents = ""
    Write-Host "In GetMethodContents method File:$codePath method:$methodNameToReturn followingMethod:$followingMethodName"  -ForegroundColor Green
    #Switch -regex (Get-Content -Path $codePath)
    #{
    #'^(.*)/s'{$contents=$switch.current}
    #}
    $contents = Get-Content $codePath | Select-String -Pattern "($methodNameToReturn.*$followingMethodName)" -AllMatches
    Write-Host "File Contents Found: $contents" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}#End of Process
}#End of Function
```

Here's example code trying to match (what's important is I get what's inside GetStatusFromCode method to parse further):

```
...
bool ClassName::GetStatusFromCode(                DWORD              errorCode,
                                                  TCHAR              *errorStr,
                                                  DWORD              &outError,
                                                  COM_ERROR_SEVERITY &outSeverity,
                                                  TCHAR              *outDevStr)
{

    m_bRestart = TRUE;

    BYTE MinorCode = 0;

    // Get and check width
    DWORD dwLength = 0;
    BYTE buff[ 2 ] = {0};
    
    //
    if ( chcusb_getInfo( (WORD)kPINFTAG_SVCINFO, buff,  &dwLength ) == FALSE ) 
    {
        // Error
    }

    MinorCode = buff[1];


    switch( errorCode ) 
    {
        //case kRESULT_NOERROR:                     
        case kRESULT_MEMFULLERR:
            //code
            _sprintf(outDevStr, _T("8000 - (Comm Err)"), errStr);
            outError = errVar;
            break;

        case kRESULT_USBNOTFOUND:                   
            //code
            _sprintf(outDevStr, _T("8001 - (Comm 1 Err)"), errStr);
            outError = errVar;
            break;
        default:
            // Maybe communication error
            
            break;
    }

    m_dwErrorCode = outError;

    if ( m_bRestart == TRUE )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////
//
// METHOD NAME:     SkipPage
//
////////////////////////////////////////
bool ClassName::SkipPage( GUID JobID, DWORD dwPageNum )
...
```

This is where I've looked for more info:

[match characters across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression)

[extract string in text file](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2150289-powershell-help-with-extracting-content-from-a-string-in-a-text-file-regex)

My question is how do I extract contents of that method name entirely? I don't care if it includes the followingMethodName, but it needs to get multiple lines until the end text of the method of interest, methodNameToReturn.  Yes, I know this is weird to want to do, but it's what is being asked for.  This is PowerShell 5.1.

Edit: I exited the powershell file and it looks like it's finding the files still, but now it's not finding anything with either regex.

Comment: If you're willing to write a bit more code, you could get all lines, iterate over them until you find one that matches the first method name, then iterate over the following lines, printing them out, until you get a match on the second name.

Comment: I don't want to print them out, I want to return from method1 to method2 in a string.  Then I'm going to parse things out of the case statements.  Right now I'm not returning anything at all from my regular expression, so it's a start.

Comment: Then instead of printing them out, you could collect them in a list, an array, or one big string.

Comment: well, once I get the method contents into a string, I will parse case contents into a list or array. Right now my regex returns nothing. Like I said, method contents needs to go into a big string to start.

Comment: @adv12 I appreciate any examples of how to do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to match multiple lines, you must get the "raw" content of the file. `Get-Content` returns a list of strings by default, but `-Raw` gives you a single string that you can match through:

```
$contents = Get-Content $codePath -Raw
```

Then to regex across multiple lines, you must capture line-ending characters. `.*` excludes line endings, so I use either `[\s\S]*` for this on windows files instead. I'm also adding `Classname::` from your example because it seems like a good place to start/end:

```
# -match usually returns true/false, so suppress
$null = $contents -match "(Classname::$methodNameToReturn[\s\S]*)Classname::$followingMethodName"

# Return the contents of the first capture group () as a single string
$Matches.Item(1)
```

More info about [-Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand what $Matches.Item(1) is.  When I Write-Host "Matches.Item(1)" it prints System.Collections.Hashtable.Item(1). That doesn't seem to be a string.  How to I further parse that for case statement contents?

Answer (score 1):

Shy of writing a fullblown C++ parser, one useful heuristic would be to consume the method body until you reach a closing `}` that corresponds to the opening `{` - the nice thing about this approach is that **PowerShell's regex operators can find them for you!**

The .NET regex engine supports something called [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups), which allows us to keep track of how many opening brackets we've encountered, and decrement the counter every time we encounter a corresponding closing bracket:

```
Select-String -Path $codePath -Pattern "(?s)$methodNameToReturn\s*\(.*\)\s*\{(?:[^{}]|(?<bracket>\{)|(?<-bracket>\}))+(?(bracket)(?!))\}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do it with Select-String as well but the regex could be just:

```
$contents = [regex]::Match($codePath,"(?s)($methodNameToReturn.*\})(.*?$followingMethodName)").Groups[1].Value
```

Probably can clean up the regex a little as well but these captures do what you want.