# Parsing Generic Type Information with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse some type information using Regex.

I've got this object that I'm targetting:

```cs
public class TypeInformation
{
    public TypeInformation(string typeName)
    {
        TypeName = typeName;
        GenericArgs = new();
    }

    public TypeInformation(string typeName, List<TypeInformation> genericArgs)
    {
        TypeName = typeName;
        GenericArgs = genericArgs;
    }

    public string TypeName { get; init; }
    public bool IsGeneric => GenericArgs.Count > 0;
    public List<TypeInformation> GenericArgs { get; }
}
```

So, if we take a `Tuple<string, int>`, that gives us a full type name of:

```
System.Tuple`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

So the format seems fairly straight forward, we've got the typename, a backtick, and then an array of the type arguments surrounded in square brackets and comma separated.

I don't believe dotnet regex supports native recursion, so to do this, I've written this parser class:

```cs
public class TypeInformationParser
{
    private static readonly Regex TypeParsingRegex = new(@"^(?<TypeName>[\w\.]+(?:`(?<GenericArgCount>\d+))?)(?:\[(?<GenericArgs>\[.+\],?)\])?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static readonly Regex GenericDetailsRegex = new(@"(?:\[(?:(?<TypeName>.+?),.+?)\])+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public TypeInformation ParseType(string typeName)
    {
        Match res = TypeParsingRegex.Match(typeName);
        Group? genericArgCount = res.Groups["GenericArgCount"];
        Group? genericArgs = res.Groups["GenericArgs"];
        Group? tName = res.Groups["TypeName"];

        if (!genericArgCount.Success) // Not a generic, lets short-circuit
        {
            return new(tName.Value);
        }

        MatchCollection genericArgsMatches = GenericDetailsRegex.Matches(genericArgs.Value);

        List<TypeInformation> genericTypeInfo = genericArgsMatches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => ParseType(match.Groups["TypeName"].Value)).ToList();
        
        // Not strictly necessary...
        int expectedNumArgs = int.Parse(genericArgCount.Value);
        if (expectedNumArgs != genericTypeInfo.Count)
        {
            throw new("Number of parsed generic parameters doesn't match signature"); 
        }
        

        return new(tName.Value, genericTypeInfo);
    }
}
```

Essentially, first I parse the top level, then I attempt to pull out just the typename part of the generic argument and parse those recursively.

So far, I've got this test which is just meant to test the ability to get the outer typename for three different types of generic: a single parameter, a multiparameter, and a multiparameter nested.

```cs
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("DeserialisePreviouslyAsPoc.Tests.TestTypes.NewNamespace.MyGenericBlob`1[[DeserialisePreviouslyAsPoc.Tests.TestTypes.NewNamespace.MyBlob, DeserialisePreviouslyAsPoc.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]", "DeserialisePreviouslyAsPoc.Tests.TestTypes.NewNamespace.MyGenericBlob`1")]
    [InlineData("System.Tuple`3[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]", "System.Tuple`3")]
    [InlineData("System.Tuple`3[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]", "System.Tuple`3")]
    public void CanParseTypeNameOfGenericTypes(string fullTypeString, string outerTypeName)
    {
        TypeInformationParser parser = new();

        var typeInformation = parser.ParseType(fullTypeString);
        typeInformation.TypeName.ShouldBe(outerTypeName);
    }
```

The first two work well and, although not in this test, seem to have parsed the rest of the fields correctly.

[image: Case One]
[image: Case Two]

However, the third case falls over.

This seems to be because the `GenericDetailsRegex["TypeName"]` matches `` System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32 `` rather than the full type (and the other args match correctly).

So, I guess the question boils down to: how do I separate out the items of a comma separated list where each item is enclosed by square brackets but can also contain square brackets and commas using regex?

So this:

```
[System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
```

Becomes this:

```
{
    [System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
    [System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
    [System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
}
```

I could probably work out where to go from there to get to:

```
{
    System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
    System.String,
    System.Decimal
}
```

Which can then be piped through recursively.

Now, I could do this by counting brackets and whatnot whilst traversing the string, but surely this is something regex can handle since I'm not trying to recurse into the structure, just match outermost matching braces.

Comment: So... at the end of the day you are just looking for a regex that matches balanced parentheses? If that's the case, use [`\[(?:(?<_B>\[)|(?<-_B>\])|[^[\]])+\](?(_B)(?!))`](https://regex101.com/r/BGbNas/1) and I'll VTC this question as a dupe of [What are regular expression Balancing Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799).

Comment: @InSync - I think that gets me most of the way there (found that question about 10 mins ago), but now I have a three regex solution which seems pretty ugly and I'm wondering if there's a nicer way, I'll throw it in as an edit and see what you think. If it's the best you can think of, I'll write it up as an answer because I think being able to parse these type strings is a useful bit of content

Comment: Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/BGbNas/2) be of use to you (arguments/parameters are stored in `Groups["Args"]`)? I don't know C#, so the answer honor is for someone else to take.

Comment: Actually yes... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this solved with a two-regex (different regexes to the question), recursive approach:

```cs
public class TypeInformationParser
{
    private static readonly Regex TypeParsingRegex = new(@"^(?<TypeName>[\w\.]+(?:`(?<GenericArgCount>\d+))?)(?:\[(?:(?<Arg>\[(?>(?<c>\[)|(?<-c>\])|[^[\]]+)+\](?(c)(?!))),?\s*)+\])?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static readonly Regex TypeDetailsRegex = new(@"^\[(?<TypeName>.+),(?:.+,){3}.+\]$");
    public TypeInformation ParseType(string typeName)
    {
        Match res = TypeParsingRegex.Match(typeName);
        Group? genericArgCount = res.Groups["GenericArgCount"];
        Group? genericArgs = res.Groups["Arg"];
        Group? tName = res.Groups["TypeName"];

        if (!genericArgCount.Success) // Not a generic, lets short-circuit
        {
            return new(tName.Value);
        }

        List<TypeInformation> genericTypeInfo = genericArgs.Captures.Cast<Capture>()
            .Select(match => TypeDetailsRegex.Match(match.Value))
            .Select(typeDetails => ParseType(typeDetails.Groups["TypeName"].Value))
            .ToList();

        // Not strictly necessary...
        int expectedNumArgs = int.Parse(genericArgCount.Value);
        if (expectedNumArgs != genericTypeInfo.Count)
        {
            throw new("Number of parsed generic parameters doesn't match signature"); // Throw custom exception type
        }
        

        return new(tName.Value, genericTypeInfo);
    }
```

The first regex, matches either a straight type-name, or, for a generic type, it pulls out the generic args into `res.Groups["Arg"]` using balancing capture groups on the square brackets.

These args are then parsed with the `TypeDetailsRegex` to get just the type-name, which is then parsed recursively.